# how can you enable partitions in Oracle 10g Enterprise Edition for Windows?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-partitioning

I installed Oracle 10g Enterprise Editions onto Windows XP.  It appeared that Partitions were installed as part of the default install, however the partitions functionality is not enabled.  I can find instructions for enabling partitions on Unix/Linux, but not Windows.  Has anybody had any success enabling partitions in 10g EE on their local machine?

thanks
Tim

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM V$OPTION WHERE PARAMETER = 'Partitioning';`

will answer the question as to whether or not partition has truly been installed.

What's it return?

Comment: Returns false.  But according to the Universal Installer > Installed Products, Partitioning was installed.

Comment: If I were you, I'd check with Oracle at metalink.oracle.com.  If you don't have a support contract, I'd recreate the database, ensuring `?/rdbms/admin/catalog.sql` gets executed and check the logs.  You may wish to try running `?/rdbms/admin/catnoprt.sql` and `?/rdbms/admin/catpart.sql`, but no warranty is expressed or implied about whether that'll hork up your database.

Comment: You know what, the next day I restarted my laptop, restarted my local 10g EE install, and poof partitioning was enabled.  Didn't change a thing.